# Presenting a changing long list, one level at a time

Tags: presentation

I will be maintaining a long list, the list of features of a program. On the one hand, this list will be too long to simply present in one or two slides plus it will grow over time, and not only at the end. On the other hand, it will be necessary repeatedly to present this list Outlook-style.

The solution I envision is to maintain the list and to be able to generate slides from it for each node. They should maintain additional text and images. Each slide should contain an "Up one level" link and each item should be a link to the lower level. Let me show you.

The List

1. One

   1. Alpha
   2. Beta

      1. Red
      2. Green
      3. Blue
      4. Yellow
2. Two

   1. Aleph
   2. Beth
   3. Gimel

      1. Top
      2. Bottom
      3. Down
      4. Up
      5. Strange
      6. Charm
   4. Daleth

      1. Dog
      2. Cat
      3. Hamster
      4. Meerkat

From this, I'd like automatically get slides like this:

**Slide 1:**

The List

1. One
2. Two

**Slide 2:**

One

1. Alpha
2. Beta

**Slide 3:**

Beta

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue
4. Yellow

**Slide 4:**

Two

1. Aleph
2. Beth
3. Gimel
4. Daleth

**Slide 5:**

Gimel

1. Top
2. Bottom
3. Down
4. Up
5. Strange
6. Charm

**Slide 6:**

Daleth

1. Dog
2. Cat
3. Hamster
4. Meerkat

Comment: So what is your question? ;-) What kind of software are you looking for? Output, input, price, OS? Please [edit] your question.